# How to recover ask question functionality on a Stack Overflow account

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions, post-ban

When I click on `Ask Question` it shows the following message.

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

For this, I google it. I get this at
[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Then I realized that this facility ban is due to that I was just asking questions, not accepting them, not visiting my account regularly and not answering questions and also at that time my reputation nearly about 58.

But the situation has changed now. I am regularly visiting, answering questions, people are accepting it (I got a nice answer badge) and my current reputation points are 678.

Though it gives me message when asking a question.

How do I recover it? By increasing reputation points or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Bans are not issued because someone asks only questions, or doesn't accept answers - usually, it's only the quality of the questions that the system looks at. However, you're definitely on the right track - keep it up!

Comment: thanks for reply... one thing can i edit my down-voted post

Comment: Yes, you can. ---

Comment: I find that none of your existing questions are below 0 net-votes and only one of the answers has a net-downvote of 1. Do you have a lot of deleted content? If so, you might need to undelete and improve them to help uplift this ban.

Comment: i didn't delete any post

Comment: You do have several deleted questions that I don't think can be salvaged. I did undelete one question that was closed as a duplicate and wrongly deleted by the community, but I don't know how much that will help. Keep trying to improve your other questions and answers and eventually the ban will be lifted.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I find it interesting that the question was closed as a duplicate of a question that was asked 20 minutes after it. If it was a canonical question it would make sense, but in this scenario it is not.

Comment: @JoshMein Yeah, that explains why the question was deleted. Thanks for looking more closely at that. (I don't think they're the same person, but it looks like the OP here and KalpeshS91 were working together on that problem.)

Comment: @shrikant1712 Another bit of advice... grammar, spelling, and capitalization is important.  I realize that English is probably not your first language, but the pronoun referring to one's self is capitalized (should be `I` not `i`).  This may seem minor, but it can help.

Comment: None of *"just asking questions,not accepting it, not visiting to my account regularly and not answering questions"* are problem behaviors, and none of them contribute to the q-ban. Read the link carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the short-url you posted.. Please read this. Continue working hard to improve.

> **How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to
>   release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?**
>
> **Automatic bans never expire or "time out."** This means that you cannot
>   simply wait for a certain amount of time: if you do not take action,
>   you will never be allowed to post again. **The only way for the ban to
>   be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.
>   Also, moderators cannot lift the ban by request.**
>
> Before you do anything else, **fix your existing posts!** As noted above,
>   down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so
>   the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any
>   objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did
>   they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled,
>   formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!
>
> **If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality
>   answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But
>   as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for
>   sure.**
>
> If you really, really think the ban is an error, then email the team
>   directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every
>   page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts is not a high
>   priority.